# TBB lost my stored passwords

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I just noticed that my installation of TBB has lost my stored passwords. Also it can't save any new passwords or even set a new master password (there has been none).
I'm not sure, but the problems seem to coincide with the installation of the latest version. I extracted the tar on top of the old installation. But I've done it like that before without any ill effect.

Any advice?

I'm using TBB 3.6.6 on Fedora 20

Follow-up on this:
 Is it the `tor-browser_en-US/Data/Browser/profile.default/key3.db` file that contains the saved password db? Because I ran a `db_verify` on it and it gave the following

```
db_verify: BDB0210 key3.db: metadata page checksum error
db_verify: BDB0522 Page 0: metadata page corrupted
db_verify: BDB0524 Page 0: pgno incorrectly set to 3523477504
db_verify: BDB0525 Page 0: bad magic number 4096
db_verify: BDB0126 mmap: Invalid argument
db_verify: BDB0530 Page 0: beyond the end of the file, metadata page has last page as 0
db_verify: key3.db: BDB0090 DB_VERIFY_BAD: Database verification failed
BDB5105 Verification of key3.db failed.
```

Any way to rescue this file or at least get the usernames/passwords in a human readable form out of it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Are you making sure you're only [signing in to web sites you trust absolutely](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AmITotallyAnonymous)?

Comment: Well, if possible, understand why the passwords were lost and recover them.

Comment: There's no website that I trust absolutely, but all the passwords were unique and randomly generated.

Comment: This is happening because TBB does not store any settings on your hard drive, and thus saved passwords are not kept when TBB is closed. (At least to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: This looks like a file corruption or forced update issue. TBB is not made for storing passwords - it's a privacy-oriented one

Answer (score 0):

Set `security.nocertdb` to `false` in `about:config`

Restart Tor Browser

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a common problem - and not just Tor-related. Browser is **not** responsible for storing your passwords at all! It's not designed to do it *properly and secure*. Especially a privacy-related bundle like Tor Browser Bundle - it's better to be reset to the blank with every execution, actually - so it's a **wrong** place to store your logins for sure! However - if you need this functionality - just use a Keepass XC manager with browser add-on! it's plugged architecture allows to implement even a complex and security-enhanced setups! And you know where your password db file is and you can make a backups for that one(it's encrypted - so it's ok to back it up as a file, basically). Use Keepass XC and it's add-on and store your passwords properly